# How can I differentiate the equation with respect to $\theta$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, differential-equations

I want to differentiate the following equation by taking $\log$ with respect to $\theta$.

$\log (\theta^{ a_H+\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{a_T+\beta-1})$

and have the result of the differentiation as below:

$\theta=\dfrac{a_H+\alpha-1}{a_H+\alpha+a_T+\beta-2}$

I am trying to learn it but not really good at doing the steps of algebra. Step by step calculations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume:

$a=\alpha_H+\alpha-1$

and

$b=\alpha_T+\beta-1$

Therefore,

$\log (\theta^{ a_H+\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{a_T+\beta-1})=\log\theta^a(1-\theta)^b=\log\theta^a+\log(1-\theta)^b={a\log\theta+b\log(1-\theta)}$

The derivative of $\log\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{\theta}$, and the derivative of $\log(1-\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ is $\frac{-1}{1-\theta}$ therefore, the derivative of the above equation is:

$\frac{a}{\theta}-\frac{b}{1-\theta}$

Apparently, you want the above derivative to become zero:

$\frac{a}{\theta}=\frac{b}{1-\theta}$

Solving the above equation is straightforward and results in:

$\theta=\frac{a}{a+b}$

which is what you want.